# Usar number field como valor de gráfica

Tags: report, pentaho

Estoy usando Pentaho Report y tengo un campo Number Field que me hace la sumatoria de una columna, el problema es que cuando quiere usar ese campo para hacer una gráfica, no me aparece en los valores. Aparecen todos los valores de mi consulta principal pero ese campo y otros que hago no me sale.

EN name: Pongo un nombre
En value: pongo la formula: = IF ([lvl] = 6; SUM([sal_eje_act]); NA())

Resumiendo. Tengo un campo number-field al que le asigno un valor y me gustaria usar ese campo en una grafica. En la grafica solo salen los campos formula  y los propios de la consulta.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea respondida con más facilidad, debes aportar más datos, código, y explicar más el problema. 
Con esos datos que das, hace muy difícil que alguien de una respuesta acertada a tu problema.